# Separating every line in a file at specific points

Tags: sed, awk, replace, split

I have a dictionary file formatted like this:

```
 A B [C] D
```

Where a is a word (with no spaces), B is another word (with no spaces inside it), C is the pronunciation (there are spaces here), and D is the definition expressed in words (there are spaces, and a variety of symbols).

I wish to separate it into 4 parts, like this:

```
 A@@@@B@@@@C@@@@D
```

In this way, the first space is converted to `@@@@`, the first `[` is converted to `@@@@`, and the first `]` is converted to `@@@@`. This will allow easy import into a spreadsheet as a CSV (`@@@@`'s serve as the commas).

Can this be achieved with `awk` or another tool in `BASH`?

Update:

Here are some samples:

```
一千零一夜 一千零一夜 [Yi1 qian1 ling2 yi1 ye4] /The Book of One Thousand and One Nights/
灰姑娘 灰姑娘 [Hui1 gu1 niang5] /Cinderella/a sudden rags-to-riches celebrity/
雪白 雪白 [xue3 bai2] /snow white/
```

Would be converted to:

```
一千零一夜@@@@一千零一夜 @@@@Yi1 qian1 ling2 yi1 ye4@@@@ /The Book of One Thousand and One Nights/
灰姑娘@@@@灰姑娘 @@@@Hui1 gu1 niang5@@@@ /Cinderella/a sudden rags-to-riches celebrity/
雪白@@@@雪白 @@@@xue3 bai2@@@@ /snow white/
```

Consider that anything might appear after the third set of `@@@@`'s, including more spaces, `[`, etc., however, before the third `@@@@`, everything is consistent in format.

Comment: Can you put up a sample record? The C and D would need special handling since they have spaces in them.

Comment: I have updated my original post to show an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think sed will be easier:

```
sed -e 's/ /@@@@/' -e 's/ [/@@@@/' -e 's/] /@@@@/' infile > outfile
```

By default (i.e. if you don't specify the `g` modifier at the end) substitutions only work once per line.

Or, if you want to do it in-place:

```
sed -i -e 's/ /@@@@/' -e 's/ [/@@@@/' -e 's/] /@@@@/' infile
```

(but not all versions of sed support that, and you'll lose your input file)

Comment: Won't the first sed substitution put "@@@@" in C and D where there are spaces? I don't think he want spaces in them.

Comment: No, without a /g flag, it only substitutes the first occurrence, like Martijn already wrote.

Comment: I just get this error: `sed: -e expression #2, char 10: unterminated `s' command`; (GNU sed version 4.2.1).

Comment: You might need to escape the spaces with a backslash, like this: `'s/\ [/@@@@/'`

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, Sorry about that. Martijn answer is correct just needed escaping the brackets which he just commented above.